# Select rows based on string pattern in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe, filter

Suppose I have the next data:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("TO for", "Turnover for people", "HC people", 
                          "Hello world", "beenie man", 
                          "apple", "pears", "TO is"),
                 number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
```

I want to filter the df based on row string pattern, if rows for name column starts with `c("TO", "Turnover", "HC")` then filter else remove.

The following code gives me a warning message:

```
library(data.table)
test <- df[df$name %like% c("TO", "Turnover", "HC"), ]
```

Console output:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(pattern, vector, ignore.case = ignore.case, fixed = fixed) :
  el argumento 'pattern' tiene tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
```

Expected output should look like this:

```
# name                   number
# TO for                   1
# Turnover for people      2
# HC people                3
# TO is                    8
```

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%like%` is not vectorized.  We may need to loop over the `pattern` `vector` and `Reduce` it to a single logical vector

```
i1 <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("TO", "Turnover", "HC"), `%like%`, vector = df$name))
 df[i1,]
#                 name number
#1              TO for      1
#2 Turnover for people      2
#3           HC people      3
#8               TO is      8
```

---

Or this can be achieved with `grepl` by collapsing the `vector` into single string with `|`

```
pat <- paste(c("TO", "Turnover", "HC"), collapse= "|")
df[grepl(pat, df$name),]
#                 name number
#1              TO for      1
#2 Turnover for people      2
#3           HC people      3
#8               TO is      8
```

Or it can be used in `%like%` as well

```
df[df$name %like% pat,]
```